# Changing date format in syslog

Tags: linux, date, freebsd, syslog

Is there anyway we can change the date format in a particular log file being logged to by syslog? I don't want to change the way all logs are being logged, but just by log file.

EDIT: I'm using syslogd (in FreeBSD)

This is how my file looks like now:

```
Dec  5 07:52:10 Log data 1
Dec  5 07:52:10 Log data 2
Dec  5 07:52:10 Log data 3
```

This is how I want it to look like:

```
20131205 07:52:10 Log data 1
20131205 07:52:10 Log data 2
20131205 07:52:10 Log data 3
```

My syslog.conf looks like this, where /var/log/my_log.log is my logfile:

```
+@
*.notice;local0.none;local1.none;local2.none;authpriv.none;kern.debug;mail.crit;news.err        /var/log/messages
security.*                                      /var/log/security
auth.info;authpriv.info                         /var/log/auth.log
mail.info                                       /var/log/maillog
ftp.info                                        /var/log/xferlog
cron.*                                          /var/log/cron
*.=debug                                        /var/log/debug.log
console.info                                    /var/log/console.log

local1.info                                     /var/log/my_log.log
```

Comment: This depends heavily on which syslog daemon you're using. Edit question with this information and you might get better responses.

Comment: `date -d"Dec  5 07:52:10" "+%Y%m%d %T"` will give you output like `20131205 07:52:10`. What I don't know is how to set the format in syslog.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using an awk script to run through the log file and replace the date field

```
awk '{getDate="date -j -f \"%b %d %H:%M:%S\" \""$1" "$2" "$3"\" \"+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S\""
      while ( ( getDate | getline date ) > 0 ) { }
      close(getDate);
      print date,$2,$3,$4,$5}' Temp1 > Temp2
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code doing? I just test it, seems it extract the format, and move to other, but -j isn't available on date in GNU/Linux. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Even if you found a different solution, I give an answer for others.

Edit your syslog configuration file (On Debian for example: `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`).

Then declare a new template like this :

```
template template_date_format {
    template("${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY} ${HOUR}:${MIN}:${SEC} ${HOST} ${MSGHDR}${MSG}\n");
    template_escape(no);
};
```

This is an example but you can use different macros according to syslog documentation linked in [user9645](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571426/user9645)'s answer.

After that, find in this configuration file, all the files you want to change the output format and apply this template to them.

For example, I want to change `/var/log/auth.log` output format, then I change :

```
destination d_auth { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
```

to :

```
destination d_auth { file("/var/log/auth.log" template(template_date_format)); };
```

Then restart syslog (`service syslog-ng restart`) and try a login to see the changes in your `auth.log`.

Comment: This is interesting, I will definitely try this out.

Answer (score 5):

There are always a new options for the date problem, adding just a couple of lines.
My solution comes adding a file to `/etc/rsyslog.d/`, for example  `myrsyslog.conf`, then add the format of your choice, mine is:

```
$template myformat,"%TIMESTAMP:1:10:date-rfc3339% %TIMESTAMP:19:12:date-rfc3339% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate myformat
```

this will apply the new format to your logs making it easy to parse.

**before**

```
Sep  3 12:52:37 whs dhcpcd[477]: wlan0: expired address ...
Sep  3 12:52:37 whs dhcpcd[477]: wlan0: part of Router Advertisement expired
Sep  3 12:52:37 whs dhcpcd[477]: wlan0: deleting route to ...
```

**after**

```
2020-09-03 13:00:49 systemd[1]: rsyslog.service: Succeeded. 
2020-09-03 13:00:49 systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service. 
2020-09-03 13:00:49 systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue using FreeBSD 9.2 and **[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/features.php)** system monitor GUI which cannot handle things like 'Jan' or 'Feb' in the date stamp (!) on the system log messages.

What I did was install the `sysutils/syslog-ng` port, and use the **[convert-syslogconf.awk](https://github.com/bazsi/syslog-ng-3.4/blob/master/scl/syslogconf/convert-syslogconf.awk)** script to migrate my `/etc/syslog.conf` to `/usr/local/etc/syslog-ng.conf` (which thankfully seemed to work well with even a fairly complex config) and added this custom formatting template to all the `file()` destinations:

```
template t_msgfmt {
    template("${ISODATE} ${HOST} ${FACILITY} ${LEVEL} ${MSGHDR}${MSG}\n");
    template_escape(no);
};
```

You can find (lots) more formatting info in the **[syslog-ng manual section 11.1](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.4-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.4-guide-admin/html-single/index.html#customizing-message-format)**. It is working good for me (so far) hope it helps you!

Answer (score 3):

Many years later rsyslog has replaced syslogd and this has gotten super easy:

```
#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
#$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

Comment out that one line and done.

Comment: To edit rsyslog config use `sudo vim /etc/rsyslog.conf`

Comment: Never know this is available for RHEL/Fedora. and it's working. Thanks!